# Settlement Period for options pre 1993

Tags: united-states, options, history, settling-and-clearing

I was reading [Settlement Period](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/settlement_period.asp) and wondering what was the settlement duration for options pre 1993. For equity/etf, it seems it was **five** days.

So for options, was it **four** days ? , any verifiable link will be appreciated.

Note: I understand that for stocks now it is T+2 and for options it is T+1.

per [link](https://www.sec.gov/reportspubs/investor-publications/investorpubstplus3htm.html) :

> Most security transactions, including stocks, bonds, municipal
>   securities, mutual funds traded through a broker, and limited
>   partnerships that trade on an exchange, must settle in three days.
>   Government securities and stock options settle on the **next business**
>   **day** following the trade.

and another [link](https://www.finra.org/rules-guidance/notices/93-77) :

> ***7*** Settlement in the **futures, options**, and government securities
>   markets occurs on the day after trade date **("T+1")** using same-day
>   funds. Settlement of most trades in corporate and municipal
>   securities, on the other hand, takes place on the fifth business day
>   after the trade date ("T+5") with money payments among financial
>   intermediaries made in next-day funds (i.e., payment by means of
>   certified checks passing between the clearing corporation and its
>   members).

So, it **seems** for Futures and options it has been always T+1, **irrespective** of what is settlement in Equity market... Any one who has been in investment for long, can please verify ?

Comment: SEC Rule 15c6-1 changed T+5 to T+3 in 1995 and it was later  amended to T+2.  My unreliable memory seems to recall that option settlement was the same as for equities but you should Google for verification.

Comment: @bob-baerker, I understand that about **stocks** , what i am looking for **options**. Has **options** been always **one** day **less** that **stocks** ?

Comment: I'm suggesting that if you can find the text and verse of the SEC rule (1995 amendment), it might spell out the different settlement changes implemented at that time for each class of securities.

Comment: From: https://www.sec.gov/reportspubs/investor-publications/investorpubstplus3htm.html option settlement been T+1 since 2004

Comment: @morrison-chang thanks for looking at the question, I am asking specifically for pre 1993

Comment: @bob-baerker, Thanks, It seems it has been always T+1

Comment: @puzzled - Did you find a source stating that it has always been T+1 ?

Comment: @bob-baerker, I did not find a source specifically stating it, but I have added some text and links in question that seems to infer that